# Read video xmp metadata iOS

Tags: ios, video, metadata, xmp, 360-virtual-reality

I need to distinguish between normal and 360 videos and for that I am trying to read the xmp metadata of a video to access the projection type of the video.
I did successfully read the metadata of an image (`CGImageMetadataRef`) but I could not have for the life of me find how to do it for videos.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.